# Index out of bounds when calculating pixel index

Tags: c#, image-processing, windows-phone-8.1

I have my image cropping app based on:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/55275a/windowsphone-image-crop-with-rectangle/

I modified it a little bit so I can resize rectangle instead of creating new

so my whole method look like:

```
private async void Accept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(image);

    double originalImageWidth = wb.PixelWidth;
    double originalImageHeight = wb.PixelHeight;

    double displayedWidth = image1.ActualWidth;
    double displayedHeight = image1.ActualHeight;

    double widthRatio = originalImageWidth / displayedWidth;
    double heightRatio = originalImageHeight / displayedHeight;

    r = (Rectangle) (from c in LayoutRoot.Children 
                     where c.Opacity == .5 select c).First();

    GeneralTransform gt = r.TransformToVisual(LayoutRoot);
    Point p = gt.Transform(new Point(0, 0));

    Point1 = (r.TransformToVisual(this)).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
    Point2 = new Point(Point1.X + r.Width, Point1.Y + r.Height);

    WriteableBitmap newImage = new WriteableBitmap(
        (int) (widthRatio * Math.Abs(Point2.X - Point1.X)),
        (int) (heightRatio * Math.Abs(Point2.Y - Point1.Y)));

    int xoffset = (int) (((Point1.X < Point2.X) ? Point1.X : Point2.X) * widthRatio);
    int yoffset = (int) (((Point1.Y < Point2.Y) ? Point1.Y : Point2.X) * heightRatio);

    if (newImage.Pixels.Length > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < newImage.Pixels.Length; i++)
        {
            int x = (int) ((i % newImage.PixelWidth) + xoffset);
            int y = (int) ((i / newImage.PixelWidth) + yoffset);
            newImage.Pixels[i] = wb.Pixels[y * wb.PixelWidth + x];
        }

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            newImage.SaveJpeg(ms, (int) newImage.PixelWidth, 
                (int) newImage.PixelHeight, 0, 100);

            image.SetSource(ms);
        }
    }
    else
    {
    }

    ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar();
    pb.IsEnabled = true;
    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(pb);
    int idReceipt = (int) PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["paragon"];
    await ReceiptsHelper.addPhotosToReceipt(image, idReceipt);
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/7.0/StronaParagonu.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

When my image is vertical everything works fine, but when my image is horizontal I get Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception at:

```
newImage.Pixels[i] = wb.Pixels[y * wb.PixelWidth + x];
```

I don't know exactly what am I doing wrong.

Anybody can help?

EDIT:
I changed my code to:

```
            if (wb.PixelWidth > wb.PixelHeight)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < newImage.Pixels.Length; i++)
                {
                    int x = (int)((i % newImage.PixelWidth) + xoffset);
                    int y = (int)((i / newImage.PixelWidth) + yoffset);
                     newImage.Pixels[i] = wb.Pixels[x * wb.PixelHeight + y];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < newImage.Pixels.Length; i++)
                {
                    int x = (int)((i % newImage.PixelWidth) + xoffset);
                    int y = (int)((i / newImage.PixelWidth) + yoffset);
                    newImage.Pixels[i] = wb.Pixels[y * wb.PixelWidth + x];
                }
            }
```

In result I've got something like [this](https://assets.okazjum.pl/uploads/uploads/receipt_photo/file/88/s3_2015_9_46_08_PM.jpg)

Maybe there is some workaround in which I can flip image 90 degree?
I tried WriteableBitmapEx but it doesnt work.

Comment: When you want get horizontal image, you must change X and Y place:                     newImage.Pixels[i] = wb.Pixels[x * wb.PixelHieght + y];

Comment: I tried this already.

Comment: Check this also: newImage.Pixels[i] = wb.Pixels[y * wb.PixelHeight+ x];

Comment: [tried](https://assets.okazjum.pl/uploads/uploads/receipt_photo/file/88/s3_2015_10_21_28_PM.jpg) 

I am trying a lot of combination, still not good.

Comment: Maybe we not understand your question. please take image from what result you want on image.

Comment: I want only part of image that is in rectangle.
[http://imgur.com/mliwJ3L](http://imgur.com/mliwJ3L)

Answer (score 0):

First thing I see is:

```
int yoffset = (int) (((Point1.Y < Point2.Y) ? Point1.Y : Point2.X) * heightRatio);
```

I guess there should be `Point2.Y`?

Second thing is what @Rashed mentioned in comment:

> When you want get horizontal image, you must change X and Y place: `newImage.Pixels[i] = wb.Pixels[x * wb.PixelHeight + y];`

But please take a note I'm really guessing here since it's late and I don't see sharp ;-)

Comment: Changed it, still this same. Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception

Comment: Sorry I didnt changed wb.PixelWidth to wb.PixelHeight 

Now I got something crazy on output:

[link](https://assets.okazjum.pl/uploads/uploads/receipt_photo/file/88/s3_2015_9_46_08_PM.jpg)

Comment: Typically, it's "y * width + height", not "x * height + width".